# phpmailer causing Cross-Origin Request Blocked on Hosting

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

I'm newbie mobile developer, I'm using phonegap as my framework also I'm using firebug to ease me looking for the error / bug that I've got.

I got this error (that I've got on firebug) :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows.....

This is my code (on server side, because maybe the culprit is the phpmailer and the ajax) :

PHPMailer :

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

include 'db_connect.php';

$applicantEmail = $_POST['PHPRequestor'];
$forgottenPass = '';

    //for checking email
    $q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '".$applicantEmail."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $q);

    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {

        echo "no email";    

    } else if ($result->num_rows == 1) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            $forgottenPass = $row["pw"];

        }

        require_once ('class_email/PHPMailerAutoload.php');                                         //include library phpmailer using auto load
        /*
        require_once 'class_email/class.phpmailer.php';                             
        require_once 'class_email/class.smtp.php';
        */

        $mail             = new PHPMailer();

        $body             = 
        "<body style='margin: 5px;'>

        <br/>
        <strong> 'Forgot Password' </strong> :
        <br/>

        <div style='width: 320px; border:#000000 solid 2px;'>

        Your pass : <strong> ".$forgottenPass." </strong> <br/>

        </div>

        <br/>
        Thanks
        <br/>

        </body>";
        $body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);


        $mail->IsSMTP();                                                            //Using SMTP

        //Activated debug SMTP to see http response
        //Enable SMTP debugging
        // 0 = off (for production use)
        // 1 = client messages
        // 2 = client and server messages

        //$mail->SMTPDebug      = 2;  

        $mail->SMTPAuth     = true;                                                 //Authentication
        $mail->SMTPSecure   = "tls"; 

        // sets the prefix to the
        $mail->Host         = "smtp.gmail.com";                                     //Set GMAIL as the SMTP  
        $mail->Port         = 587;                                                  //Set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server


        $mail->Username     = "myemail@email.com";                                  //Email
        $mail->Password     = "thepassword";                                        //Password 

        //This will add 'Your Name' to the from address, so that the recipient will know the name of the person who sent the e-mail.
        $mail->SetFrom("myemail@email.com", "Request Forgot Password");             
        $mail->AddReplyTo("myemail@email.com", "Request Forgot Password"); 
        $mail->Subject      = "Request Forgot Password', user : ".$applicantEmail; 
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);

        $address = "targetemail@email.com";                                         //target email
        $mail->AddAddress($address, "'Permintaan Lupa kata sandi'");                    

        if($mail->Send()) {

            echo "success";

        } else {

            echo "Oops, Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            exit;

        }

    }

$con->close();
```

?>

Ajax (using jquery)

```
function sendForgotPassword(FPEmail) { 

    var requestor = FPEmail;

    //create form_data for post data on ajax PHP
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("PHPRequestor", requestor);

    $.ajax ({

        type: "POST",
        url: to_phpSide,

        data: form_data,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        beforeSend: function() {

            loadingPageW(1);

        },
        success: function(data){

            if (data == 'success') {
                //when success

            } else if (data == 'no email') {
                //when no email 
            } else {
                //when error or something else occured
            }
        }, //for error message
        error: function (xhr, errorStats, errorMsg) {

            alert("error: "+xhr.errorStats+" , "+errorMsg);


        },
        complete: function() {

            loadingPageW(2);

        }

    });
```

};

I already tried in localhost and work well.
But when I trying on hosting, I've got error (on top).

I'm really curious, if the error because of my page trying to request something that cross domain,
then why on the other pages (that I using same method, but without phpmailer) work nice on hosting?

Is there something error? Or method that I miss?

> FYI :
>
> 1. I already check about SMTP (phpmailer) support on my hosting and that's support well.
> 2. I'm not place the html page in hosting, I just place the .php in hosting
> 3. Also I already try : [How to specify the SMTP server in PHPMailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193030/how-to-specify-the-smtp-server-in-phpmailer)
>
> But still not a chance.

Thanks,
Any help would be appreciate :)

---

-Edit :
On my firebug (console) there's no error that I got, I already activated `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`, but I couldn't see the error or something else, the response is just empty (nothing there)
I just see

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows.....

---

-Edit 2 :
By the request @synchro about the URL that causing the error, below is the full error :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http:// myhost/www/myphp. This can be fixed by
>   moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

note :
myhost is refer to page that I used for hosting.
myphp is the .php file that contain code above (PHPMailer code)

Comment: This is nothing to do with PHPMailer. PHPMailer runs entirely server-side, and the cross-origin error is client side. Firebug should be showing you the URL of the request is that's being denied, and that info is vital in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: @Synchro thanks for pointing out what going on here. :) So my client side is the one that causing this error (Cross-Origin Request Blocked)? - See my update to the URL that you need to diagnosing my problem

Comment: Like the error says - move the URL it's accessing to your domain and it will no longer be cross-origin.

Comment: Thanks for giving the solution, but I still a bit confuse about your solution. The 'URL' that you said, is the "http:// myhost/www/myphp" ? or the local URL that I used (since I use HTML (in localhost), to access my .php in hosting). I just wondering, is there any solution that I can do to surpass that error without moving the URL (also without JSONP)? Thanks anyway @Synchro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you serve your page from `http://localhost/index.php` and it talks to `http://somewhereelse/index.php`, that's cross-origin because the domains do not match. You can solve that in several ways:

- Set `access-control` headers as others have described
- Proxy the request on your own server so it doesn't appear cross-origin to the browser.
- Do whatever it is that the target script does on your own server

The last of these is the simplest.

Also it looks like you're using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an old example. Get the latest [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and look at the examples and wiki.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest and solution that you've give to me :) I'm still trying.. Also, I already use the latest version of PHPMailer (I used from the link that you've give to me). Thanks to you, I already found the real culprit here :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code in your PHPMailer:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: Sorry, just want to clarify. That code add into all of my PHPMailer class? (also 'PHPMailerAutoload.php'?) or you mean, the code above that I post? || Edited : I've tried that, and still not a chance.. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Remove top three lines (starting with header) and put there code i have provided above.

Comment: Sorry, still same error I've got, any other suggest? :)